# Building on Ubuntu 16, missing SSL during ./configure

Tags: ssl, openssl, dependencies, make

I am trying to build bitcoind on Ubuntu 16 64-bit. I have installed the dependencies and have built it fine many times on other machines.

During ./configure, I am getting

```
checking whether the Boost::Unit_Test_Framework library is available... yes
checking for dynamic linked boost test... yes
checking for mismatched boost c++11 scoped enums... ok
checking for SSL... no
configure: error: openssl  not found.
```

I have run `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev` and tried it, also tried `brew install openssl`, still no dice.

Before, I was getting a missing pkg-config at this point, even though I had installed it. I installed pkgconf and also installed it via brew, and now it's complaining about openssl, which is definitely installed.

```
$ which openssl
/usr/bin/openssl
```

Any ideas? Frankly, I'm stumped.

UPDATE:

I built openssl from source, now I'm getting this:

```
checking for mismatched boost c++11 scoped enums... ok
checking for SSL... yes
checking for CRYPTO... yes
checking for EVENT... no
configure: error: libevent not found.
```

I'm not sure what is going on... it seems it cannot find packages installed via apt-get for some reason.

Comment: I didn't want to set this as an answer, because it's really not. I set up a new server with Ubuntu 14 and it worked the first time. Very strange. Did some directory paths change in Ubuntu 16?

Comment: I guess you didn't follow https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-unix.md (builds fine at ubuntu 16.04), Looks like you haven't installed `libevent-dev` and `libssl-dev`.

Comment: I absolutely did install both of them, multiple times I uninstalled and installed via apt-get and brew, I tried both. It only progressed past each package in the ./configure file once I built from source.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the issue by installing extra libraries, the whole list

```
sudo apt-get install -y autoconf g++ make openssl libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev

sudo apt-get install -y libcurl4-openssl-dev pkg-config

sudo apt-get install -y libsasl2-dev
```

Source: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/issues/138#issuecomment-184749966